# Chrome extension: Default width for popup less than max width?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, popupwindow

I'm relatively new to programming and am working on a Chrome extension with a popup. I don't know the content in the popup, nor do I know the users' preference (obviously). The popup should be able to be resized horizontally, but I want a default (initial) width less than the max width.

In popup.html I have a `<div id="container">` element for the popup.

In the associated CSS file, I have:

```css
body{
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
}
```

and

```css
#container{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The content fills up the entire popup, pushing the popup to the max size (800x600) if needed. There is a vertical (height) scrollbar on the popup if necessary, just as I want.

My issue is the width; the popup will automatically change width to fit the content when the content is loaded. The popup may start out at 400px, but then it will widen to the full 800px once content is loaded if the content is 800px or wider.

Since the user can adjust the width of the popup, I want to specify some reasonable default width, which is less than the popup max width, and let the user widen or narrow the popup, should they choose to do so. Having the popup be the full 800px wide isn't desirable as the "out of the box" behavior.

I can use `body{max-width: 400px; min-width: 400px;}` to force a popup width. But some users may want the popup to be wider, so I don't want to do this. I'd like to make the initial width 400px, for example, but still allow resizing of the popup.

Is there a way to set a default width for the popup that is *less* than the max popup width even if the content is wider than this default width, but still allow resizing (widening) the popup?

Sorry if I've left out important information or this is a bad explanation. I tried to search the web and play around but so far it's been to no avail. I appreciate any help teaching me how to conquer this situation.

Comment: Try something like this? I don't know if it will work or not, though. http://www.cybertext.com.au/tips_HTML_window_size.htm

Comment: Thanks Torr3nt. Unfortunately, Chrome extensions with manifest version 2 don't allow inline scripts so this solution gets more complicated.

Comment: I added `window.resizeTo(<w>,<h>);` to the initialization function in the JS code for the popup (triggers on `'load'`), but this doesn't solve the initial widening of the popup when content is first loaded. I appreciate your help!